# Convert bytearray from a VARBINARY(16) column into an IP address

Tags: python, arrays, byte, pyodbc, vertica

I need to extract large amount of data from a HP Vertica database and save it to a file. I am using official ODBC driver from Vertica with pyodbc.

This is what I have done so far:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Vertica};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=db;UID=user;PWD=pw')
cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
cnxn.setencoding(str, encoding='utf-8')
cnxn.setencoding(unicode, encoding='utf-8')
cur = cnxn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM schema.table LIMIT 3")
```

Then I read the data

```
for row in cur:
    print row
```

Most of the fields are returned just fine - unicode text, numbers or datetimes. However for a field that stores IP Addresses I get the following:

```
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\no\x19\\')
```

How do I convert it to text?

Any help with be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What is the corresponding column type in the table definition? Do you know the IP address that those bytes are supposed to represent?

Comment: @GordThompson the corresponding column type in the table definition is varbinary(16). I don't know which IP address those bytes correspond to. It's not easy with my current set up to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see there's an accepted answer but... for all the others:

If your data is in Vertica the **very** first thing to do is to check the fine SQL Reference Manual. In this case you will find a built-in function to convert IPv6 address represented as VARBINARY column to a string.

Much simpler and much, much faster:

```
SELECT V6_NTOA(your_column_here) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

VARBINARY(16) is 128 bits, which is just the right size for an IPv6 address. The sample data decodes to

```
0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:0a6f:195c
```

and the "IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses" subsection of the Wikipedia article on IPv6 (ref: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv6_readiness)) says that such an address is an IPv4 address (32 bits) mapped into an IPv6 format (128 bits).

```
::ffff:10.111.25.92
```

We can generate those string representations above from the raw `bytearray` data using a function like this:

```python
def bytes_to_ip_address(byte_array):
    if byte_array[0:12] == bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff'):
        return '{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}'.format(byte_array[12], byte_array[13], byte_array[14], byte_array[15])
    else:
        return ':'.join(['{0:02x}{1:02x}'.format(byte_array[i], byte_array[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(byte_array), 2)])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # examples
    fld = bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\no\x19\\')
    print(bytes_to_ip_address(fld))  # 10.111.25.92
    fld = bytearray(b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\no\x19\\')
    print(bytes_to_ip_address(fld))  # 0100:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:0a6f:195c
```

Or, with Python3 we can use the [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module:

```python
import ipaddress


def bytes_to_ip_address(byte_array):
    ip6 = ipaddress.IPv6Address(bytes(byte_array))
    ip4 = ip6.ipv4_mapped
    if ip4 == None:
        return str(ip6)
    else:
        return str(ip4)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # examples
    fld = bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\no\x19\\')
    print(bytes_to_ip_address(fld))  # 10.111.25.92
    fld = bytearray(b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\no\x19\\')
    print(bytes_to_ip_address(fld))  # 100::ffff:a6f:195c
```